# Type checks for null-coalescing operator with dynamic operand

Tags: c#, .net, type-safety, null-coalescing-operator

Consider the following, minimal example:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Dictionary<string, int> obj = GetDynamic() ?? new List<string>();
    }

    private static dynamic GetDynamic() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code will compile, but fail at runtime because the `List<T>` cannot be converted into a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. I guess this is because the expression `GetDynamic() ?? new List<string>()` resolves to type `dynamic` at compile time.

Is there a way to force a compilation error when either of the operands of the null-coalescing operator does not match the expected return type?

Comment: You can't force the default compiler to raise an error message here. But I guess you could develop your own Roslyn extension to generate a custom error message. Didn't do something like that before, so I can only suggest to google for "c# roslyn extension" or something like that.

Comment: That already happens. The real problem is that `dynamic` can always be converted to something else, albeit with an implicit conversion that may fail at runtime. There is no (compile-time) typing error here. You can force one, of course: `(Dictionary<string, int>) GetDynamic() ?? new List<string>()` -- but that requires that you know `dynamic` is involved. All other workarounds I can think of are even more involved and require contrived rewrites of `??` that you wouldn't use in actual code unless you already knew about the issue (which defeats the purpose).

Comment: Why do you use `dynamic` if you already know the returned type? Change `dynamic` to `Dictionary<string, int>` and you will get the compile-time error as you want. If you don't know the returned type, then your code design is flawed and you will get a runtime error when it returns anything other than `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Comment: @RacilHilan this is obviously an academic question. `GetDynamic` maybe an third-party API-method OP can't change. And the point of the question is "type-safety": how to avoid this kind of mistakes at compile-time.

Comment: The example is extracted from a legacy app that uses `dynamic` for configuration purposes. I just stumbled accross such a bug within the app and wondered why the compiler can't tell something's wrong here (as it's pretty obvious for a developer).

Comment: @RenéVogt And you inferred all of that from the question? You have some super powers :). It doesn't matter if it is the OP's design or a third party. A bad design is a bad design and there is nothing that can safe-guard against it. Returning dynamic from a third party library is even a worse design than returning it in your own code, because like you said, you have no control over it and don't know what's going on. Avoid using bad libraries or you sign yourself in for a pile of troubles.

Comment: If you want static typing, don't turn it off by explicitly using `dynamic`, whose *sole purpose* is to turn off static type checking.  If this code were to generate a compiler error then *it wouldn't be doing its job*, and that would be a bug in the language.

Comment: *why the compiler can't tell something's wrong here*, because the developer who wrote the code explicitly told the compiler not to check. When you use `dynamic`, the compiler will not check. The complier only checks the first argument against the type, and then checks if the second argument type can be implicitly converted to the first one's. In your case, `List<T>` can be converted to `dynamic`, so the compiler is happy.

Comment: @RacilHilan: That's actually not true. You can swap the arguments and the code will still compile (so the compiler just checks the return type of the expression). Nevertheless, you're all right about the "expecting a known type and assigning a dynamic type to it"-thing. I will change the code accordingly (getting rid of dynamic here is way too much effort) and add an answer that the compiler derives type `dynamic`. Thanks for the discussion anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the compiler can't tell something's wrong here (as it's pretty obvious for a developer).

Because the developer who wrote the code explicitly told the compiler not to check. When we use `dynamic`, we're effectively telling the compiler to turn off static type checking.

Using `dynamic` in that way is not a good design. If you don't know the returned type, then the code design is flawed and you will still get a runtime error when it returns anything other than `Dictionary<string, int>`. Change `dynamic` to `Dictionary<string, int>` and you will get the compile-time error as you want.

This may answer your question, but it's not in any way a good thing to do. If you cast the `dynamic`, you will get the compiler error:

```
Dictionary<string, int> obj = (Dictionary<string, int>)GetDynamic() ?? new Dictionary<string, int>();
```